CORS - CSRF token Mismatch with Laravel 11 Sanctum & React on Different Domains
I’m working on a Laravel 11 backend (https://backend.com) with Sanctum for authentication, and a React frontend hosted on a different domain (https://frontend.vercel.app). I’m encountering a CSRF token mismatch error when trying to authenticate via Axios in React.
.env settings (Backend):
APP_URL=https://backend.com
APP_FRONTEND_URL=https://frontend.vercel.app

SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
SESSION_ENCRYPT=false
SESSION_PATH=/
SESSION_DOMAIN=null
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=frontend.vercel.app
SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=true
SESSION_SAME_SITE=none
SESSION_PARTITIONED_COOKIE=true

Config/Cors.php:
    'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['https://frontend.vercel.app'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,

React Axios Code:

await axios.get("https://backend.com/sanctum/csrf-cookie", {
        withCredentials: true,
      });

const axiosInstance: AxiosInstance = axios.create({
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "X-XSRF-TOKEN": Cookies.get("XSRF-TOKEN"),
    },
  });

await axiosInstance.post("https://backend.com/api/login",
          {
            email,
            password
          }
        );

Despite following the documentation and setting SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS and CORS correctly, I am still getting a CSRF mismatch error when logging in. Any ideas on what might be missing?
